# wifi network unclaimed : broadcom

Tags: release-loki, wifi, ethernet

My wifi connectivity has recently stopped. I am using an HP Probook with elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki.

I use the app manager to maintain my software state. As far as I can tell the device is still there.

It would seem I have a Broadcom card!

I have read a few posts and have run the following the diagnostics.

```
dave@pcdflhp:~$ uname -a
Linux pcdflhp 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dave@pcdflhp:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
ens5      no wireless extensions.

dave@pcdflhp:~$ sudo nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled      enabled  enabled         enabled 

dave@pcdflhp:/var/lib/NetworkManager$ cat NetworkManager.state 
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

dave@pcdflhp:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0700000-d0703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 03
       serial: b4:99:ba:e6:ef:c7
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw ip=192.168.1.91 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff memory:d0600000-d061ffff
```

I have uninstalled & reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.271

Any ideas?

Comment: I had come to the conclusion that this was a bug somewhere in the OS, and I ran an OS update tonight and it's now working again. (It was just the OS.)

Comment: I opened this question because most similar questions seem to be hardware specific and also the remediations proposed didn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has cleared itself up after an OS component update using the AppCenter. It downloaded 6 components.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on my MacBook.  I removed the BCM STA kernel update and reinstalled via terminal commands.  It appears that the wl module make is failing with a error, so no driver is created.  I don't know how to fix, but this may help someone who does.